# Pass variable value from one javascript to another

Tags: javascript, .net

I have created Master Page `EXAMPLE1.Master` for my .net web application. Their I am storing value in JavaScript variable. I want to retrieve that variable in another JS File.

EXAMPLE1.Master:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var pageAccess = '<%=Session["UserAccess"]%>';
            masterPageLoad();
        });
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JS/pageActions.js">
</script>
```

pageAction.js

```
//Retrieve pageAccess variable here.
```

Definition of `masterPageLoad();` is present in pageAction.js file

Comment: Can't you pass a parameter to `masterPageLoad()` ? That's what parameters are designed for !!

Comment: i dont want value in just masterPageLoad() i want it in all functions in pageAction.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your `pageAccess` variable, before `$(document).ready(function() {`

like

```
var pageAccess = '<%=Session["UserAccess"]%>';
$(document).ready(function() {
   masterPageLoad();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your variable declaration outside the function

```
var pageAccess = '<%=Session["UserAccess"]%>';
$(document).ready(function() {
        masterPageLoad();
});
```

This variable should now be visible in any JS file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable if you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    masterPageLoad('<%=Session["UserAccess"]%>');
});
```

And then update your pageActions.js accordingly:

```
function masterPageLoad(pageAccess) {
    ...
}
```

But if you need to work with an external variable, the reason it's currently not working is that it's defined within the scope of the DOMReady handler. You should either extract the variable declaration to be outside of the DOMReady handler, or you should create a global variable:

```
window.pageAccess = '<%=Session["UserAccess"]%>';
```